# Python: Use list containing index values to split another list

Tags: python-3.x, python

I have a list of tuples which represent the coordinates of a shape - "points"

I also have a list of index values which identify the starting point for each part of that shape (since a shape can contain one or more 'islands') - "parts"

Currently, to extract a part's points from the points list I do the following:

```
points = [
    (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (0, 0),
    (4, 5), (5, 4), (3, 6), (2, 9), (4, 5),
    (2, 2), (3, 2), (6, 4), (4, 4), (8, 6), (4, 3), (2, 2)
]

parts = [0, 5, 10]

for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    start = part

    try:
        end = parts[index + 1]
    except Exception:
        end = len(points)

    print(points[start:end])
```

However, this does not feel particularly Pythonic to me. To be honest, the use of the exception just feels downright dirty. Can anyone suggest an improved Python v3 methodology for this particular problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
parts = [0, 5, 10, len(points)]
start_end_pairs = zip(parts[:-1], parts[1:])

for start, end in start_end_pairs:
    print(points[start:end])
```

#### Explanation

Your `parts` already contains the starting indices, so you only need to take the contents of that array to calculate what you want.

From `[0, 5, 10]`, you need to take `(0, 5)` for the first part, `(5, 10)` for the second, and `(10, len(points))` for the third part. The process of creating these pairs to use in the `print`-loop can easily be implemented with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip). I zip the two arrays:

```
[0, 5, 10]
[5, 10, len(points)]
```

to produce

```
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, len(points))]
```

which is exactly what you need.

Comment: There are some bloody clever people on StackOverflow. Thanks Irfy.

Comment: Glad to help. If you like the way I used `zip` above, try taking on some functional programming lectures/tutorials; it made me a better programmer back in the days (and that's where I first saw `zip`).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(parts)):
    if i==len(parts)-1:
        print(points[parts[i]:])
    else:
        print(points[parts[i]:parts[i+1]])
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(parts)-1):
    print(points[parts[i]:parts[i+1]])
print(points[parts[-1]:])
```

or:

```
for start, end in zip(parts[:-1], parts[1:]):
    print(points[start:end])
print(points[parts[-1]:])
```